# How to check whether a file/ folder exist on remote desktop?

Tags: python, filesystems, remote-desktop

I am trying to access a local drive (Windows computer) from the remote desktop (also Windows). During which I need to check whether a certain folder/ file exist. However `os.path.isfile()` and `os.path.isdir()` only works on local file.

How can I check whether a certain folder/ file exists on a local drive on remote desktop by python?

Comment: I think it really depends on which platform you're trying to do this and which protocol it uses, e.g. something mounted on Windows with UNC/Samba might be different than any machine using SSH or so.

Comment: How can I check for the protocol?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Should I delete this question or leave it as sort of guidance for the others that might used the wrong keywords?